# get text from a div with class and itemprop

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the text from this:

```
[<div class="menu__vendor-name" itemprop="name">Beno's Flowers &amp; Gifts</div>, <div 
class="menu__vendor-name" itemprop="name">Bluebird Diner</div>, <div 
class="menu__vendor-name" itemprop="name">Bread Garden Market</div>]
```

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 url = 'https://www.chomp.delivery/restaurants'

 headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '\
       'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '\
       'Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36'}

 response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

 restaurant_wrapper = soup.find(class_ = "dd_rest_list")
 restaurants = restaurant_wrapper.find_all(class_="menu__vendor-name", 
 itemprop="name")
 
 def extract_restaurant_data(restaurant):
   results = [
    {
        "title": print(title.text.strip())
    }
    for title in restaurant_details
    ]

  print(results)

  results = [extract_restaurant_data(restaurant) for restaurant in restaurants]
```

Output:

```
 AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I am thinking that the issue is that each div has an itemprop, maybe this is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your goal is to scrape some details from each restaurant and not only its name. Change your strategy - process the data in same way you will read it and store it more structured in a `list` of `dicts`:

```
results = []

for restaurant in soup.select('.dd_rest_list a'):
    results.append({
        'title':restaurant.find('div',{'itemprop':'name'}).text,
        'url':'https://www.chomp.delivery'+restaurant.get('href'),
        'address':restaurant.find('div',{'itemprop':'address'}).get_text(',',strip=True) if restaurant.find('div',{'itemprop':'address'}) else None,
        'and':'so on'
    })
```

Always check if element you like to select exists before calling a methode:

```
'address':restaurant.find('div',{'itemprop':'address'}).get_text(',',strip=True) if restaurant.find('div',{'itemprop':'address'}) else None,
```

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.chomp.delivery/restaurants'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '\
   'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '\
   'Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

results = []

for restaurant in soup.select('.dd_rest_list a'):
    results.append({
        'title':restaurant.find('div',{'itemprop':'name'}).text,
        'url':'https://www.chomp.delivery'+restaurant.get('href'),
        'address':restaurant.find('div',{'itemprop':'address'}).get_text(',',strip=True) if restaurant.find('div',{'itemprop':'address'}) else None,
        'and':'so on'
    })
results
```

##### Output

```
[{'title': '2 Dogs Pub',
  'url': 'https://www.chomp.delivery/r/21/restaurants/delivery/Burgers/2-Dogs-Pub-Iowa-City',
  'address': '1705 S 1st Ave Ste Q,Iowa City,IA,52240',
  'and': 'so on'},
 {'title': 'Alebrije Mexican Restaurant',
  'url': 'https://www.chomp.delivery/r/3316/restaurants/delivery/Mexican/Alebrije-Mexican-Restaurant-Iowa-City',
  'address': '401 S Linn st,Iowa City,IA,52240',
  'and': 'so on'},
 {'title': 'Ascended Electronics',
  'url': 'https://www.chomp.delivery/r/2521/restaurants/delivery/Retail/Ascended-Electronics-Iowa-City',
  'address': '208 Stevens Dr,Iowa City,IA,52240',
  'and': 'so on'},
 {'title': 'Aspen Leaf Frozen Yogurt',
  'url': 'https://www.chomp.delivery/r/522/restaurants/delivery/Ice-Cream-Sweets-Snacks/Aspen-Leaf-Frozen-Yogurt-Iowa-City',
  'address': '125 S Dubuque St,Iowa City,IA,52240',
  'and': 'so on'},...]
```